# Story, show or movie where having sex causes the main character to lose their powers for a limited time

Tags: story-identification, powers

Honestly....this is ALL I can remember about it. The Main hero was incredibly strong and had various abilities, but he would lose his powers for a day or so after having sex. [and yes, it was a "he"].

This was not *the Darkness* comic book [Jackie Estacado would die and his powers pass on to his unborn son if he got someone pregnant]. Nor is it *Angel:The Series* where our Vampire hero couldn't have a "single moment of happiness" or he'd lose his soul.

I don't know if this is a trope of sorts, or if its been done in other shows. so any suggestions to other similar works could lead to the exact show, so... feel free to suggest them.

Comment: Can you remember when you read/saw this? Can you remember what media it could have possibly been?

Comment: Honestly...._no!_  It came back to me in a discussion my brother and I were having, but **neither of us** could remember it; we were just discussing that plot point, because it _really_ stuck out.

Comment: This often happens to me after sex, all I can do then is fall asleep for about ten hours

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**"Argoman the Fantastic Superman" (1967)?**

Here is the 2nd paragraph from Wikipedia which describes Argoman's servant worrying about him being intimate with the villainess because he will lose his powers for six hours.

> At the Tower, Scotland Yard Inspector Lawrence investigates the theft
>   of the Royal Crown. Sir Reginald Hoover (Argoman) trains to hold his
>   breath under water in a pool (his servant Chandra tells him the result
>   is 33 minutes, 9 seconds). Afterwards, Sir Reginald invites one of his
>   girlfriends for a rendezvous and picks Samantha, a young Englishwoman.
>   Suddenly, he hears a hovercraft nearing the shore and uses his
>   telekinetic powers to get it ashore. From the hovercraft emerges a
>   woman who introduces herself as Regina. Sir Reginald invites her to
>   spend time with him. However, Chandra is worried, because following
>   intimacy, Argoman will lose his powers for six hours.

This Italian movie was released on video in the U.S. as "The Incredible Paris Incident". You can watch the complete movie on YouTube, but I posted the trailer below. At 22 seconds you can see part of the scene where Argoman loses his powers after intimacy:

Comment: Yep, that's it, I think. Now I know why it was so hard to find; never knew the name of it, but remembered the odd costume and out of synch mouth movements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be *[Hancock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hancock_(film))*?

Will Smith plays Hancock, a superhero with a bad temper. Invulnerable and immortal, until he meets another one like him, a woman.

As Wikipedia explains:

> That night, Hancock stops a liquor store robbery, only to be shot multiple times, and is hospitalized. Mary appears, explaining that when the immortals paired up, they would slowly lose their powers, becoming mortals.

It's not necessarily after *sex* though, just being in each other's vicinity was enough.

Comment: It also wasn't for a day or so, the power loss wasn't really a repeatable event. Though there are strong similarities to the details in the question.

Comment: No, _definitely_ wasn't Hancock; I've owned that movie for years, and he and Charlize never even really kissed, let alone had sex. This was more a recurring aspect.

Comment: Cool, no prob. It's just as useful to know what it _isn't_.